# My Zendesk targets are giving Net::ReadTimeout errors even though my API is working

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config, zendesk, zendesk-api

We have a set of APIs (PHP) linked to our Zendesk via targets. Zendesk is sending data to our endpoints just fine, but we're seeing `Net::ReadTimeout` errors in our "Target Failures" tab.
This error is generated when the response cannot be read within the set `read_timeout`. [Link](https://www.exceptionalcreatures.com/bestiary/Net/ReadTimeout.html)

I have increased `max_execution_time` to 120 even though it was already set to 30 (which seems plenty but ok why not) and I have also set on each of my PHP script the following:

```
set_time_limit(120);
```

It doesn't seem to fix the issue. I restarted Nginx on my server but I'm still seeing the same issues popping up on our dashboard.

Zendesk is rather vague as to what exactly should be done here. I have also made sure a proper `200` status code is generated by adding :

```
http_response_code(200);
```

That won't help either.

I don't know where to look in my logs to track how long a given request took on a given endpoint. If anyone knows that...

If anyone with a bit of experience with the Zendesk API, could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also added :
`header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 200', true, 200);` and even though the header response is containing the correct status, it's still giving me the Net""ReadTimeout error

Answer (score 0):

This problem is well explained in [this thread](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360038514734-Net-ReadTimeout-on-Webhooks-even-though-data-is-coming-through?page=1#community_comment_360010157674):

The problem is that the timeout is defined at Zendesk side with a limit of 10 seconds. Recommended approach is to make the APIs asynchronous, i.e., won't wait for execution completion to give the response back ot Zendesk.